# Wrap text of columns made with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I want to wrap the text and set a column width to my code, but the answers in the other questions have a different type of pandas code.

This is an example of the answer in another answer, my question is how to apply 'text_wrap': True to my code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticket': ['a','b','c','d'],
                  'Category': [2,1,4,3]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Trial Version.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook=writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

# Setting the format but not setting the column width.
worksheet.set_column('A:B', None, format)

writer.save()
```

This is my code.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
df.transpose()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('immowelt_Property_listing.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

What i want is the output excel to come with a predefined column width and every column with it text wraped.

Comment: the predefined width can be achieved with `worksheet.set_column('A:B', your_width, format)`

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Just apply that to your code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
df.transpose()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('immowelt_Property_listing.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook=writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

# Setting the format column A-B width to 50.
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 50, format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Not working on my end with pandas 1.4.3 and python 3.9